# opencv android crashing after 10 sec

Tags: android, opencv

I've been using a tutorial script that uses opencv to apply a greyscale filter to the camera images. The script works fine (runs continuously), but when I modified the script in order to filter out blue/green colours and only show red, after 10 secs the activity closes with the following warning/error messages

```
05-18 15:24:36.765: W/ContextImpl(6067): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV:24 org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync:79 
05-18 15:24:37.983: W/Adreno-EGL(6067): <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateContext:2349>: EGL_BAD_CONFIG
05-18 15:24:37.983: E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(6067): Cannot create OpenGL context
```

I'm not sure what those messages mean. And I'm not sure what could cause a program to crash after running for awhile. Could it be a memory problem?

This is the section of code that I've been modifying

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

//Original code
//Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);

Core.split(mRgba, channels);
// m = Core.mean(channels.get(0));
channels.set(1, Mat.zeros((channels.get(1)).rows(), (channels.get(1)).cols(), (channels.get(1)).type() ));
channels.set(2, Mat.zeros((channels.get(2)).rows(), (channels.get(2)).cols(), (channels.get(2)).type() ));

Core.merge(channels,mRgba);
//return mGray;
 return mRgba;
}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
package com.example.camera1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.*;

//import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mGray;
private List<Mat> channels=new ArrayList<Mat>();
Scalar m;
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private int rowsize;
private int colsize;
private int ktype;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
@Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
switch (status) {
case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
{
Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
} break;
default:
{
super.onManagerConnected(status);
} break;
}
}
};
public MainActivity() {
Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);

mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
super.onPause();
if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}


public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
mGray = new Mat();
mRgba = new Mat();
channels=new ArrayList<Mat>();

}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

//Original code
//Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);

Core.split(mRgba, channels);
// m = Core.mean(channels.get(0));
channels.set(1, Mat.zeros((channels.get(1)).rows(), (channels.get(1)).cols(), (channels.get(1)).type() ));
channels.set(2, Mat.zeros((channels.get(2)).rows(), (channels.get(2)).cols(), (channels.get(2)).type() ));

Core.merge(channels,mRgba);
//return mGray;
 return mRgba;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution? I ran into the same issue.

Comment: calling the garbage collector every 100 or so iterations like the answer below ended up solving the problem. if I didn't call it often enough it would crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling garbage collector explicitly inside the `onCameraFrame` method might solve the issue:

```
    System.gc();
```

As @xMKx has already noticed, the problem is likely to be connected to memory management. Application just runs out of the heap and then terminates.

The problem is that for some reasons  garbage collector sometimes ignores `Mats` that have no references to them. So this is the case when using `release()` method of Mat objects would not produce any results (unfortunately).

Comment: @mou have you checked the memory usage? Is it the problem?

Comment: yes and its very weird, when I run "adb shell dumpsys meminfo" it shows a growing usage, but just after I call it, its cleaning it, so I can keep the app on just by calling it, its the native mem usage growing, system.gc doesnt help :(

Comment: apparently its because I m creating a new mat this way: Mat res = new Mat(from.rows(), from.cols(), from.type()); I can't get it to free, even with .release() or System.gc(). 
I finally handled to use the same Mat instead of creating new one each frame... its not a crazy idea, but thats the only thing which worked

Comment: Lifesaver answer. @MaxMalysh Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try releasing all of the Mats in the ArrayList after your done processing with it. I've had similar issues, but it all led down to memory management.(not sure if it was the same error message)